# Can I validate the domain name of HTTP request?

Tags: java, http, cookies

I have a Java web application, with a single entry point URL, and an external web app redirects to that URL. Can I check on the server-side that the request has come from a particular domain using cookies or whatever?

**EDIT:**
I cannot change the external app code

Comment: Can you change the way the external server redirects to your Java web app? I mean the code, or the url?

Answer (score 4):

I think that you want to know the HTTP Referer (the URL that "called" your page):

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

**EDIT**

I forgot that, as *gustafc* said, the HTTP referrer is a client-controlled value and can be spoofed to something entirely different or even removed by the client, so you cannot be sure that your HTTP Referrer is not a fake value

Answer (score 3):

You can check the [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), but it's not reliable: It's easy to fake, and some choose to disable referers for privacy reasons. So while it may work most of the time, don't rely on it for security or other essential concerns.

What are the *real* reasons for trying to do this?

Comment: The main reason is security. In fact, there is an encrypted key in the request which can be quite enough for that, but I have the requirement to additionally check the domain name.

Comment: You can try to make a dns request and sees that if the results match the HTTP referer.

Comment: @DmitryTikhonov Are you trying to verify that the user reached your website by clicking their way from the other website, or are trying to verify that the user's request originates from a certain domain (i.e., basically check the user's IP)? I just sort of assumed the former, which is impossible (and imho be pretty useless); the latter is quite feasible, as described by other posters here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can get the origin of the request from `getRemoteHost()` or `getRemoteAddr()` method in the request object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost()

Comment: Not a suitable solution for me, because `getRemoteHost()` returns last proxy, not the redirect originator

Comment: Some proxies pass the original client IP as a header. E.g. Apache mod_proxy uses `X-Forwarded-For`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to verify that the request is from a specific IP (or IP range) you can configure a rule at your firewall to support this (assuming the proxy is within the firewall.